# Netbeans Can't Git

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control, ide

I'm trying to commit some changes to a file using Git with Netbeans. When I right click the file and go to commit it, after I enter my comment and press the submit button, this happens:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing tree d9bc543071955676c211b28ae1699396e811dfac
```

But when I use the command line I can commit the file just fine.

How has the tree gone missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: What Netbeans version are you using? on what OS, with what java version, and what JGit version is included as a plugin in your Netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans 7.2.1, Windows, and I'm not sure about jgit. How can I tell?

Comment: I believe this is JGit1.3. Can you update it to 2.1 and see if the issue persists? See last comment of netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221737

Comment: I suggest to use git only via command line since you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse may be doing more steps than needed when making a commit, but even so, it's bad if there is an object that is needed, but is missing.

Make sure `.git/objects/d9/bc543071955676c211b28ae1699396e811dfac` exists and is readable to Eclipse.
If it doesn't exist, try to find that same file in someone else's git folder of the same project (or in the main bare repository) and copy it into your git directory so you would have it.